# Error [ValidationError] failed: _id: Cast to ObjectID failed for value "" at path "_id"

Tags: javascript, nodejs, angular, mongodb, mongoose

Estoy haciendo una consulta con **Angular** 9 y **NodeJS**

```
export class Vehiculo {
    constructor(
        public _id: String,
        public matricula: String,
        public tipo: String,
        public modelo: String,
        public color: String,
        public name: String,
    ) { }
};
```

Este es el modelo que uso para formar el tipo Vehiculo

```
vehiculo(project: Vehiculo): Observable<any> {
  let params = JSON.stringify(project),
    headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  return this._http.post(this.url + 'vehiculo/', params, { headers: headers });
}
```

Este es el servicio que utilizo en Angular para envíar el json

```
this.vehiculos = new Vehiculo('', '', '', '', '#000000', '');
```

En el componente lo inicializo y todo en el constructor

Este es el modelo de vehiculo

```
const vehiculoSchema = new Schema({
    matricula: {
        type: String,
        require: true,
        trim: true,
        unique: true
    },
    tipo: {
        type: String,
        trim: true
    },
    modelo: {
        type: String,
        trim: true
    },
    color: {
        type: String,
        maxlength: 7
    },
    cliente: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Cliente',
        required: true
    }
});
```

La función que uso para guardarlo en la base es

```
const Vehiculo = require('../models/vehiculo'); //* Calls vehiculo.js model
```

Importo el modelo de vehiculo y luego importo dentro la de Cliente para usarlo

```
saveVehiculo(req, res) {
    if (!req.body) return res.status(400).send({ error: 'Bad Request' });
    const newVehiculo = new Vehiculo(req.body);

    const Cliente = require('../models/cliente'); //* Calls cliente.js model

    Cliente.findOne({ name: req.body.name.toLowerCase() }).select('_id').exec((err, cliente) => {
        if (err) return res.status(500).send({ error: 'Internal Server Error' });
        if (!cliente) return res.status(404).send({ error: 'Cliente Not Found' });
        newVehiculo.cliente = cliente._id;
        console.log("TCL: saveVehiculo -> newVehiculo", newVehiculo)
        newVehiculo.save((err, vehiculoStored) => {
            console.log("TCL: saveVehiculo -> err", err)
            if (err) return res.status(500).send({ error: 'Internal Server Error' });
            if (!vehiculoStored) return res.status(204).send({ error: 'Vehiculo No Content' });
            return res.status(200).send({ data: vehiculoStored });
        });
    });
}
```

El console.log de TCL: saveVehiculo -> newVehiculo me lanza

```
TCL: saveVehiculo -> newVehiculo {
  _id: 5e5996de5824cd05906bfe4f,
  matricula: 'ACC-ADS-8989',
  tipo: 'Camioneta',
  modelo: 'BMW',
  color: '#000000',
  cliente: 5e53e36dac093d32a46c7d2c
}
```

Y el console log de TCL: saveVehiculo -> err

```
TCL: saveVehiculo -> err Error [ValidationError]: Vehiculo validation failed: _id: Cast to ObjectID failed for value "" at path "_id"
    ...
    at Kareem.execPost (D:\Node\parkingLot\backend\node_modules\kareem\index.js:217:3) {
  errors: {
    _id: MongooseError [CastError]: Cast to ObjectID failed for value "" at path "_id"
        ...
        at next (D:\Node\parkingLot\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10) {
      stringValue: '""',
      kind: 'ObjectID',
      value: '',
      path: '_id',
      reason: [MongooseError],
      message: 'Cast to ObjectID failed for value "" at path "_id"',
      name: 'CastError'
    }
  },
  _message: 'Vehiculo validation failed',
  name: 'ValidationError'
}
```

No sé qué estoy haciendo mal.

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar el esquema de Mongoose para el modelo Vehículo?

Comment: Ya lo puse @MauricioContreras

Comment: Hola, cuando haces find en mongoose los ObjectIds que devuelve no son un string. prueba de cuando haces esto: "newVehiculo.cliente = cliente._id;" poner .toString() al final. Asi: "newVehiculo.cliente = cliente._id.toString();"

Comment: @JordiBaliellasPortet ya lo intenté y sigue sin funcionar :c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es muy claro en el mensaje de error que te muestra Mongoose:

> _id: MongooseError [CastError]: Cast to ObjectID failed for value "" at path "_id"

**PROBLEMA**

Se desea crear un documento de MongoDB a partir de datos enviados desde el frontend (Angular) hacia el backend (NodeJS/Express/Mongoose). En la vista se tiene un modelo del documento que se inicializa así:

```
this.vehiculos = new Vehiculo('', '', '', '', '#000000', '');
```

Y como podemos observar en la clase de dicho objeto tenemos 6 campos definidos todos de tipo `String`:

```js
export class Vehiculo {
    constructor(
        public _id: String,
        public matricula: String,
        public tipo: String,
        public modelo: String,
        public color: String,
        public name: String,
    ) { }
};
```

Hasta allí todo está perfecto. Sin embargo, cuando enviamos dichos datos al backend e instaciamos el modelo en el back, estamos estableciendo el campo `_id` que viene del front como un caracter nulo: `''`:

```
const newVehiculo = new Vehiculo(req.body);
```

Cuando intentas luego salvar este documento, MongoDB intenta usar el campo `_id` que viene definido como carácter nulo en tu solicitud y no puede hacer la conversión del mismo (*Cast*) en un objeto ObjectID válido.

**SOLUCIÓN**

La solución es sencilla y puedes hacerlo de muchas formas. Mostraré al menos 2 para que escojas la que mejor se adapte a tu aplicación.

**Crear el objeto de tipo ObjectID e inyectar su valor antes de enviar el documento a salvar**

En esta solución simplemente vamos a crear un valor de tipo [ObjectId](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#mongoose_Mongoose-ObjectId).

Para ello debemos usar el método adecuado de Mongoose [`ObjectId()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#objectids):

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
// ...
const newVehiculo = new Vehiculo(req.body);
newVehiculo._id = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId();
```

De esta forma estaremos cambiando el valor que viene desde el front, por un valor de `ObjectId` válido.

Ahora, esta forma de resolver tiene un detalle, y es que los valores de `ObjectId` generados así no serán correlativos o en todo caso del mismo patrón que los que genera tu Base de Datos. Y aunque es válido hacerlo de esta forma, a veces se requiere que todos los valores del campo `_id` sean generados automáticamente por la BD.

**Eliminar el campo conflictivo y dejar que MongoDB genere el campo**

Otra forma de resolver el problema es eliminando el campo que genera conflicto en tu documento o crear el documento sin dicho campo, esto requiere hacer algunos ajustes en el código: bien sea eliminando directamente la propiedad una vez que has instanciado el modelo (puedes usar la sentencia [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/delete) de Javascript) o creando el modelo a partir de los campos no confilctivos de tus datos.

Veamos la solución usando `delete`:

```js
const newVehiculo = new Vehiculo(req.body);
delete newVehiculo._id;
```

Eso fue sencillo, ¿cierto?

La otra forma es creando un objeto con los campos no conflictivos de tus datos:

```js
const newVehiculo = new Vehiculo({
  matricula: body.matricula,
  tipo: body.tipo,
  modelo: body.modelo,
  color: body.color,
  name: body.name,
});
```

También fue fácil.

De esta forma al enviar el documento a la BD para salvarlo, MongoDB detectará que no tiene un campo `_id` y lo creará al momento de salvar el documento.

Espero que esto te ayude a solucionar tu problema.

Comment: Gracias. Poco antes de tu respuesta en el modelo de Typescript en Angular le quite el public _id String

Comment: Claro, pero si necesitas dicho valor en el front para alguna tarea específica después de salvar el documento en DB, entonces no es buena idea quitarlo, ya que romperías tu modelo de datos en la vista. Mejor buscar la solución como te la comento en la respuesta. Saludos

Comment: En todo caso, al momento de instanciar el modelo para enviarlo al back le pones a dicho campo `undefined`, por ejemplo: `this.vehiculos = new Vehiculo(undefined, '', '', '', '#000000', '');`. Con esto el campo llegará vacío y Mongo podrá hacer la conversión. Como te comenté, soluciones hay muchas. Debes buscar la que mejor se adapte a tu proyecto. Mi respuesta se basa en ajustes en el lado backend, pero es válido hacerlo en el frontend. Saludos